# ddrescue recovering from extfat drive to ntfs drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs, ddrescue

I am recovering an external hardrive (exfat) and storing the image file in ntfs drive.

I made source drive to be read-only.

Speed is very slow. Ddrescue is operating in B/s.

Command I used in ddrescue is:

```
sudo ddrescue -d -r 3 source destination logfile
```

In the source drive I used to store videos. When I copied the files from one drive to another (general copy, no tool) in ubuntu ,error occured :I/O error . That is why I am using ddrescue to backup the files to another drive.

Am I doing something wrong?
Should I use another tool and not ddrescue?
Can ddrescue help me in backing up here?

What should be the command for speeding up the process?

Comment: If you have IO errors, you cannot speed up the process - it's slow, and will be slow because the drive should just be replaced, you forget about whatever data is on it, and just restore your backups.  Data recovery is slow - why we backup anything we value.

Comment: What backup should I restore? What backup are you referring to? Is it the 60gb .img file recovered from ddrescue

Comment: Whatever backups you created of your data before your drive failed. As I don't know what backup strategy you implemented (to prevent data loss), I can't know what restoration of data options you have available. Data recovery tools are slow, esp. on failing/failed equipment (with IO errors), so just forgetting the dead/dying drive, replacing it with a new drive & restoring data from backups is the easy & normal solution. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: Soory I did not had any backup plan.So Now i am stucked